# Additional conditions under which separately continuous implies joint continuous

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be compact metric spaces and consider $f:X\times Y\rightarrow X$ a separately continuous function.

I am wondering if there could be some additional conditions on $f$ (for example $f(\cdot,y):X\rightarrow X$ being surjective or injective for every $y\in Y$) which would grant the joint continuity of $f:X\times Y\rightarrow X$.

The strongest result I have found is [contained in this article by Namioka](https://msp.org/pjm/1974/51-2/pjm-v51-n2-p23-s.pdf) and states that in this case there is a dense subset $A\subset Y$
 such that $f:X\times A\rightarrow X$ is joint continuous, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are compact, a necessary ans sufficient (and a bit trivial) condition is that all $f(\cdot,y)$ are continuous, and all  $f(x,\cdot)$ are *equicontinuous* (or viceversa).

Comment: Maybe you have some algebraic conditions on $f$? Like $X,Y$ are compact topological groups and $f(\cdot,y)$ is a homomorphism for every $y$. Then you can try to derive the joint continuity from the existence of many continuity points (given by the Namioka Theorem)?

Comment: Unfortunately, in my setting there are no additional algebraic conditions

Answer (score 2):

Young [1] proved that for $X=\mathbb R$ (or $X=[0,1]$) the monotonicity of $f(\cdot,y)$ implies the joint continuity.

[1] W. Young, A note on monotone functions, The Quarterly Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics (Oxford Ser.) 41 (1910), 79–87.

Answer (score 0):

It is a well-known result of Functional Analysis/Topological Vector Spaces [1] that every linear map from a finite dimensional normed space to any topological vector space $E$ is continuous (=jointly continuous).

[1]: Rudin, W. (1991). Functional analysis, mcgrawhill. Inc, New York.

Comment: This seems unlikely to be helpful in the setting which the original questioner was asking about